# Filter derived class by base class property

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, c#-4.0, covariance

I have two classes (Car/Truck) that share a base class (Automobile). I would like to filter collections of both Car and Truck by a property on their base class, Automobile. The code below causes an error:

> ```
> Cannot implicitly convert type   
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Example.Program.Automobile>' to    
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Example.Program.Car>'
> Program.cs    48  27  Example
> ```

Is it possible to filter by the base class property without having to convert the results back to their appropriate derived class?

```
class Program
{
    public class Automobile
    {
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

        public static  IEnumerable<Automobile> GetByManufacturer(IEnumerable<Automobile> items, string manufacturer)
        {
            return items.Where(o => o.Manufacturer == manufacturer);
        }
    }

    public class Car : Automobile
    {
        public int TrunkSize { get; set; }
    }

    public class Truck : Automobile
    {
        public int BedSize  { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var cars = new List<Car> 
        {
            new Car { Manufacturer = "Toyota", TrunkSize = 100 },
            new Car { Manufacturer = "Kia", TrunkSize = 70 }
        };

        var trucks = new List<Truck> 
        {
            new Truck { Manufacturer = "Toyota", BedSize = 400 },
            new Truck { Manufacturer = "Dodge", BedSize = 500 }
        };

        // Problem: Get a list of Type Car and a List of Tpye Truck, 
        // where each List contains only cars manufactured by Toyota
        var mfr =  "Toyota";

        List<Car> toyotaCars = Automobile.GetByManufacturer(cars, mfr).ToList();
        List<Car> toyotaTrucks = Automobile.GetByManufacturer(trucks, mfr).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(toyotaCars.First().GetType().Name);
        Console.WriteLine(toyotaTrucks.First().GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that this line may be a type:
    `List<Car> toyotaTrucks = Automobile.GetByManufacturer(trucks, mfr).ToList();`
trucks are not derived from cars, although the share the same base type. You could either declare the list using the more base type, like so:
    `List<Automobile> toyotaTrucks = Automobile.GetByManufacturer(trucks, mfr).ToList();`
Or you can use the more derived type
    `List<Truck> toyotaTrucks = Automobile.GetByManufacturer(trucks, mfr).ToList();`
but to use trucks as a list of car you'll have to cast the type from Truck to Car, which you probably don't want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your definition to

```
public static IEnumerable<TAuto> GetByManufacturer(IEnumerable<TAuto> items, string manufacturer)
                    where TAuto : Automobile
{
    return items.Where(o => o.Manufacturer == manufacturer);
}
```

Right now you are returning an `IEnumerable<Automobile>`, then call `ToList` which converts it to a `List<Automobile>`, then try to cast it to a `List<Car>` which is not legal because the list *could* contain `Automobile`s that are not `Car`s.

With the change you will be returning an `IEnumerable<Car>`, which is perfectly convertible to a `List<Car>`

Also, the return type in the second call should be `List<Truck>`, not `List<Car>`:

```
List<Truck> toyotaTrucks = Automobile.GetByManufacturer(trucks, mfr).ToList();
```